# iirf rewrite url

Tags: url-rewriting, iirf

i'm trying to use iirf for what  looks like asimple rewrite but it's not working.
what i need:
rewrite http://www.mydomain.com/ru  to : http://www.mydomain.com?page=russian
the objective being that a get param would be sent but the user would see the first url on their browser's url bar.
 i'm using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine ON
StatusUrl /iirfStatus

RewriteRule  http://www.mydomain.com/ru  http://www.mydomain.com?page=russian
```

1. does this go (the iirf file) on the site's root or in a 'ru' subfolder (tried both)?
2. what am i doing wrong or missing?

thanx and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
RewriteRule  ^/ru$  /?page=russian [I,L]
```

You should put this in the `iirf.ini` file in the web sites root folder.

Check http://www.mydomain.com/iirfStatus to see whether iirf was able to read your configuration file.

Also, you may use `RewriteLogLevel` with a value of 2 or 3 and `RewriteLog` to see whether the incoming url was rewritten, and how (or why not).

Comment: thank you for a very helpful answer, problem solved :-)
btw - http://www.domain.com/iirfStatus returns a page not found. where is the log file located?